# Reinstall xcode simulator runtimes

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

```
r-7-99-25-172:Desktop a$ xcrun simctl list runtimes
== Runtimes ==
iOS 10.3 (10.3.1 - 14E8301) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-10-3)
tvOS 10.2 (10.2 - 14W260) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.tvOS-10-2)
watchOS 3.2 (3.2 - 14V243) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.watchOS-3-2)
r-7-99-25-172:Desktop a$ ls /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes
r-7-99-25-172:Desktop a$
```

I have iOS 10.3 runtime listed with xcrun but it's not in /Profiles/Runtimes or under XCode's Components:
[image]

How can i reinstall iOS 10.3 so that it's properly showing up?

Comment: dont you have a simulator with that iOS version? please run this command on terminal and post the output "xcrun simctl list"

Comment: whats your problem.. your simulator is not working?

Comment: @MarcioRomeroPatrnogic I couldn't get a react native app to run on it (Error: Process exited with non-zero code: 22). It didn't work after resetting content and restarting either, so I'm trying to reinstall it to see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: go XCode>Preferences>Locations.. which version of command line tools do you have selected?

Comment: @MarcioRomeroPatrnogic Xcode 8.3.3 (8E3004b)

Answer (score 1):

The Components pane shows what content is available as downloadable content.  Xcode comes bundled with the latest iOS Simulator runtime (in your case, iOS 10.3.1), so it is not listed in the Components pane as it does not need to be installed.

Based solely on the data you have provided, there is nothing wrong with your system.